# Show that matrix $A(XB^{-1})^ = $ to $X = C^T(A^{-1})^TB$

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, matrix-calculus, transpose

I'd like to ask how we arrive from: $A(XB^{-1})^ = $ to $X = C^T(A^{-1})^TB$. A, B and C are all invertible matrixes. I was already thinking to apply the rule $()^ = ^^^$ like the following:

1. $A(XB^{-1})^ = $
2. $A(B^{-1})^TX^T = $
3. $(A(B^{-1})^TX^T)^T = ^T$
4. $XB^{-1}A^T = ^T$

but now I am stuck and don't know how to arrive at $X = C^T(A^{-1})^TB$. How do I solve this (intuitively)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{alignat*}{3}
& \left[A(XB^{-1})^T\right]^T &= &C^T \\
\iff & \big[(XB^{-1})^T\big]^TA^T &= & C^T \\
\iff & XB^{-1}A^T & =&  C^T \\
\iff & XB^{-1} &=& C^T(A^T)^{-1}\\
\iff & X &=& C^T(A^T)^{-1}B
\end{alignat*}

Using $(A^T)^{-1} = (A^{-1})^T$

> $$X = C^T(A^{-1})^TB$$

Comment: Thank you for your insight! So if I distill from your answer correctly it means when you flip the $A^T$ from the left to the right it turns into $(A^T)^{-1}$ and is placed at the end. Could you maybe point me to the property that states that (implicit) rule?

Comment: You may find it here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose

Comment: And if you're looking for a proof, then this will be useful. https://yutsumura.com/the-inverse-matrix-of-the-transpose-is-the-transpose-of-the-inverse-matrix/